# Call to JNI crashes after android service is restarted?

Tags: android

I have an android service that uses a native library via NDK/JNI. The native library is statically loaded/initialized as suggested...

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");
    if (!nativeClassInit())
        throw new RuntimeException("native init failed");
}
```

Everything works fine until the service is stopped (e.g., from a UI activity where the service may be started/stopped). The problem is when the service is stopped the task has not yet been killed by android and if the user restarts the service the native libraries are not reloaded and a call to a native function causes a crash in the native code?

I tried calling the nativeClassInit() method again after a restart but this doesn't help?
Also, I seen in other posts that unloading the native library is not allowed in Android.

Comment: What is the native code trying to do when it crashes, and what is the error?

Comment: Do you preserve some JNI pointers (JniENV, jobject-s, etc.) on native side between Service restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by making the service run in its own private process and having the service kill itself in its onDestroy() method via android.os.Process.killProcess() solved my problem. Not sure if this is the most correct way but I would be happy to hear any suggestions.

Concerning the above comments...

What is the native code trying to do when it crashes, and what is the error?

```
The native code crashed as soon as an internal native library function was called just before the crash an __android_log_print was done displaying the correct parameter values passed in. Its hard to say what exactly happened from the dump.
```

Do you preserve some JNI pointers (JniENV, jobject-s, etc.) on native side between Service restarts? 
     Yes, I preserve the JVM in the Onload method and also JNI class IDs & method IDs in my static initialization method. I tried recalling the static initialization method but the same crash occurred.